# Python documentation in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there a way to integrate standard Python documentation into Eclipse? So it will be possible to press F1 on an API function and get its description in the Help view of Eclipse.

I use PyDev.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had the same problem, so I kinda made an Eclipse plugin for that purpose.

Or download from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydoc/)

Comment: pydoc.tk is down. Would be nice if the Sourceforge page included an installation instruction.

Comment: It does now. So this is just a docs.python.org browser, no context search?

Comment: yes.not sure what context search you want, but the docs.python.org provides a search form at the left frame.

Answer (score 5):

PyDev, nor Eclipse, does not provide integrated on-line help for the Python documentation. Unlike with Java, Python API source code documenting has several competing documentation standards and implementing support for them would be difficult.

However if the function under the cursor can be resolved its docstring is shown in a pop-up note.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Also because Python is dynamic language, as opposite to static languages like Java, you rarely can resolve functions to their source in code development time.

Using Python console debugger you can use the help() command when the application is being run

```
  >>> help(obj.myfuction)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know about help() and pop-up hint on a function and use them all the time. But for examples and more detailed documentation I go [here](http://docs.python.org). It's a pity that those docs could not be integrated (any way it will be relly hard to do) into IDE.

Comment: I personally use duckduckgo.com as my browser search engine. If you type in query !python xxx it will search from Python docs. Also if you type in !pypi xxx it will search from Python package repositories.

Comment: Looked through [http://duckduckgo.com/tech.html](http://duckduckgo.com/tech.html). Many nice "!" things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of, but that would be very useful in pydev. You should suggest it in the eclipse pydev [forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/forums/forum/293649) ,or code it yourself! If I was still a CS student I'd help..

Comment: I hope it will be there at some point. I'll go take a look at that forum now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Zeal - https://zealdocs.org/

Although I do not see how to integrate it in Eclipse, it is pretty useful next to it on your desktop. And it is not only Python docs, but may more. A real life saving stuff this Zeal docs!

---

*Just a footnote: I do not use Eclipse that much as I switched to PyCharm and Jupyther.*