# Getting documentation and source of OpenCV Python to eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, opencv

I installed OpenCV Python (3.1.0) and found a way to get code completion into Eclipse (Neon.1) [How to use code completion into Eclipse with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085643/how-to-use-code-completion-into-eclipse-with-opencv). As I know it from other Python libs, I would like to have the documentation for a method by hovering and look into its source (Alt + click). I am not quite sure if this possible, due to the C/C++ implmentations. I am working with Python 2.7 and Win7.

Thanks for solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is available here: [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/).

*But I could not find a way to include it to Eclipse.*

This answer is related to my problem: [Python documentation in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790276/5625518)